# How to add custom navigation bar in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-controls, navigationbar

I am going to create a Wordpress website using 2017 Wordpress theme and I want it to be fully customized design. So I am trying to use my own navigation bar design in it.

For now I have remove default navigation bar in php file and add custom html and css code. But it is not actually what I want. I want it to be fully customisable from wordpress admin panel. For a example if I add new page it should add to navigation bar like normal function in Wordpress. But for now each and every page I have to update navigation bar manually. Can you provide solution for this?

Comment: https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-add-custom-navigation-menus-in-wordpress-3-0-themes/

Answer (score 0):

1. You need register menu `register_nav_menu`
2. Use `wp_nav_menu` for showing menu in your template
3. For full customization markup for menu you can use `wp_nav_menu( [ 'walker' => new My_Menu_Walker() ] );`
4. Create class `My_Menu_Walker` and customize all elements.